# Convert date string to UTC time with PHP

Tags: php, date

I have the following date string

```
$date="Sat Apr 30 2011 18:47:47 GMT+0900 (Tokyo)"
```

I want to convert it to UTC time

```
$timestamp_UNIX = strtotime($date);
echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z",$timestamp_UNIX);
```

Why do I got

```
2011-04-30T11:47:47Z
and not
2011-04-30T09:47:47Z
```

Comment: What's your `date.timezone` preset? The value is either set in the `php.ini` or via `date_default_timezone_set()`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you code does not automatically echo UTC. It echos the timestamp in whatever your default timezone is set to. This is done via [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) at runtime or via the configuration setting [`date.timezone`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) in your `php.ini`.

The *modern* way would be to use the [`DateTime`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and the [`DateTimeZone`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) classes.

```
$d = new DateTime('Sat Apr 30 2011 18:47:47 GMT+0900 (Tokyo)');
print_r($d);
$d->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
print_r($d);
```

prints

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2011-04-30 18:47:47
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => +09:00
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2011-04-30 09:47:47
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
```

Comment: Do you think the default time zone is +7 instead of +9 in the php.ini file? Anyway I have no acces to this file and it would mean that each server would output a different date... I will have a look at date_default_timezone_set(). I keep you in touch

Comment: The default timezone is most likely something with a `+2` hour offset from UTC (e.g. `Europe/Berlin` is currently 2 hours off from UTC due to daylight saving). `date_default_timezone_get()` will help you to determine your default timezone.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `gmdate()` instead of `date()` (or you could check the DateTime and DateTimeZone classes in PHP 5.2 / 5.3)

Comment: Sorry I don't use date() in my code. The date I have is a string which is always written with this format.

Comment: You do use date() in your question. It provides the output:`echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z",$timestamp_UNIX);` If you change that to gmdate() you'll be fine.

Comment: Yes I could correct the offset of the unix timestamp by using gmdate. But it wouldn't change the fact that the Unix timestamp has two hours of offset.

Comment: The unix timestamp is fine, it's just the time zone of your php script. That is either explicitly (in your code somewhere) or implicitly (as a server configuration) set to GMT+0200.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DateTime` class. This method allows you to explicitly set the timezone and format of the input string.

```
$stringDate = "Sat Apr 30 2011 18:47:47 GMT+0900 (Tokyo)";
$date = new DateTime($stringDate, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```