# Convert datetime from GMT to regular time

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to convert a string date to the correct timezone value, I would really appreciate any help. I've tried the following.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT-5');
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
```

**Source:**
2011-12-28T00:14:33-05:00

**GMT offset value:** -05:00

**String to time:**
1325049273

**format:** "j M g:ia"

**Showing as:**
27 Dec 9:09pm

**Should be showing as:**
28 Dec 12:14am

Comment: check with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840978/convert-date-string-to-utc-time-with-php  for some reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $d = new DateTime('2011-12-28T00:14:33');
    echo $d->format('j M g:ia');
```

this worked =?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `date_default_timezone_set('GMT');`

Try this

```
<?php
$source = '2011-12-28T00:14:33.000-05:00';
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT-5');
$date = new DateTime($source);
echo $date->format('j M g:ha');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
$newTZ = new DateTimeZone("Etc/GMT-5");
$date = new DateTime($your_source, $UTC );
$date->setTimezone( $newTZ );
echo $date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Try this, it might work for you.

Comment: i think you can edit the format string. I'm not sure about that.